# Error with crypto in Libjingle compile

Tags: scons, libjingle

When I compile the latest libjingle,I found some issues as below:

```
scons: Building targets ...
________Compiling build/dbg/obj/third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.o
third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.c:56: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘err_level’
third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.c:69: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.c:72: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘err_reporting_init’
third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.c: In function ‘err_report’:
third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.c:96: error: ‘va_list’ undeclared (first use in this function)
third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.c:96: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.c:96: error: for each function it appears in.)
third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.c:96: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘args’
third_party/srtp/crypto/kernel/err.c:98: error: ‘err_level’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
```

Can anyone give me advice as to how to solve this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with the libjingle libraries however the error that the compiler is referring to is because the ./configure command (should have been previously ran) should have set the target (your computers) architecture type... x86, x86_64, arm etc

You should research the compile options for the package in question

Comment: many thanks for your advise.It seems missing some command in configure.Try again.

Comment: fixed.It's a include path issue.

Comment: how did you fix this? it seems when I specify isysroot the compiler can't find the relative include paths.

Comment: never mind - fixed by removing -I/usr/include from main.scons